# Google Speech to Text - LongRunningRecognize - PollUntilCompleted returns buy operation is still not complete

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

This is my code:

```
        var speech = await SpeechClient.CreateAsync();
        RecognitionAudio recognitionAudio = RecognitionAudio.FromStorageUri(cloudStorageUri);

        var operation = speech.LongRunningRecognize(new RecognitionConfig()
        {
            Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
            SampleRateHertz = 16000,
            LanguageCode = "en-GB",
        },  recognitionAudio);

        while (!operation.IsCompleted) // never completes
            operation.PollUntilCompleted();

        var response = operation.Result;
```

I don't understand why "PollUntilCompleted" returns yet operation.IsCompleted is still falls.

Comment: Have you tried the sample code at the C# STT Client library? It includes the use of the method pollUntilCompletedAsync. Adding it to the next comment

Comment: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Speech.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Speech.V1.SpeechClient.html#Google_Cloud_Speech_V1_SpeechClient_LongRunningRecognize_Google_Cloud_Speech_V1_LongRunningRecognizeRequest_Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_CallSettings_

Comment: @KevinQuinzel That's the same as my code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with the client library. Using "gcloud" CLI tools worked just fine. I've just noticed now the disclaimer at the top of the page:

> The Speech-to-Text v1 is officially released and is generally available from the https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech endpoint. The Client Libraries are released as Alpha and will likely be changed in backward-incompatible ways. The client libraries are currently not recommended for production use.

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/async-recognize#speech_transcribe_async_gcs-gcloud